# Same code blocks about function template compiled ok under g++ but error under VC6, why?

Tags: c++, function-templates

I am reading the chapter "function templates" of *C++ Primer 3rd edition*, and when I tried to follow the example, I found the code almost the same as the book has encountered an error during compilation under VC6 but everything is ok under g++. I don't know why?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
T1 my_min(T2 a, T3 b)
{
    return a>b?b:a;
}

int main()
{
    int (*fp)(int, int) = &my_min<int>;
    cout<<fp(3,5)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error happened under `VC6` appears like:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from '' to 'int (__cdecl *)(int,int)'
None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
```

Comment: Don't have any solid info so not putting in an answer. But it could be that VC6 is horribly old and broken. Try a newer version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VC6 is an ancient compiler whose support for templates is woefully lacking, so it cannot cope with legal code in many circumstances. You should ditch it and download [VS 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) instead.